# How to include the external style sheet in dom pdf

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using Dompdf for the report generation in the php. I am not able to include the external style sheet for the same...

The code I am using is similar to the following:

```
<?php
require_once "dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

$html ="
<table>
  <tr >
    <td class='abc'>testing table</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class='def'>Testng header</td>
  </tr>
</table>";

$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->set_base_path('localhost/exampls/style.css');
$dompdf->stream("hello.pdf");
?>
```

Please let me know how to include the external css file..

Comment: What's the exact error message? Also share the relevant code you're using, if any.

Comment: Hi @Dan..style sheet are not loading in the generated pdf.

<?php
require_once "dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();


$html ="
<table>
  <tr >
    <td class='abc'>testing table</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class='def'>Testng header</td>
  </tr>
</table>";

$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->set_base_path('localhost/exampls/style.css');
$dompdf->stream("hello.pdf");
?>

Comment: For the comment above it would be better to edit your post to clarify the question.

Answer (score 14):

`$dompdf->set_base_path()` isn't where you specify your CSS. That method gives you the opportunity to define a base path that is appended to relative paths in the document.

Your CSS should be part of the HTML you feed to dompdf. Something like the following:

```
<?php
require_once "dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

$html ="
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="localhost/exampls/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr >
    <td class='abc'>testing table</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class='def'>Testng header</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>";

$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->set_base_path('localhost/exampls/style.css');
$dompdf->stream("hello.pdf");
?>
```

Think of dompdf as a web browser that renders to PDF instead of a screen. You feed it a valid HTML document just like you would any web browser.

Comment: Excellent analogy to understanding dompdf. Much easier to think of now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what helped me for v1.0.2. I have little bit specific use case in which I am generating PDF from CLI.

```
 $dompdf->getOptions()->setChroot($this->projectDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'www');  //path to document root
```

and then

```
 <link type="text/css" href="build/css/pdf_results.css" rel="stylesheet"/> //must not start with slash
```

When calling CLI script from another directory than document root, you have to also set

```
$dompdf->setBasePath($this->projectDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'www');
```

Answer (score 0):

dompdf supports the some CSS 2.1 selector syntaxes. dompdf also supports elements with multiple class attributes (`e.g. <p class="red bold">foo</p> matches p.red and p.bold`).

Note that the CSS selectors are case sensitive in dompdf (e.g. `.foo` will not match `<div class="FOO">bar</div>`)

Read http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility or Git https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility

Refer [DOMPDF doesn't work with external css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185531/dompdf-doesnt-work-with-external-css-file)

[CSS not working with DOMPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008637/css-not-working-with-dompdf)