# Why the generated pdf doesn't is not CSS styled?

Tags: css, laravel, pdf, tailwind-css, dompdf

I have a view welcome.blade.php with the headear like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <title>Blog</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/example.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
</head>

<body class="font-sans antialiased w-full">

....
```

I'm using tailwindcss, this page has a responsive layout with many colors, svgs, etc. And it's working fine, however I'm trying to generate a pdf of this page with barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. But when the pdf is downloaded it doesn't have any style, no colors, it has a serif font, and the layout is all unorganized.

Route for the pdf functionality:

```
Route::get('/', [PDFController::class, 'generatePDF']);
```

PDFController:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;

class PDFController extends Controller
{
    public function generatePDF()
    {
        $data = [
          'title' => 'PDF Title',
          'author' => 'Author'
        ];

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('welcome', $data);
        return $pdf->download('test.pdf');
    }
}
```

Do you know what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style and view are not automatically inherited, domPdf needs to be fed a specific view and css in order to work properly.

Have a look here:

[How to include the external style sheet in dom pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805148/how-to-include-the-external-style-sheet-in-dom-pdf)

and this is a very detailed guide on how to achieve that:

https://www.positronx.io/laravel-pdf-tutorial-generate-pdf-with-dompdf-in-laravel/

Comment: Thanks, do you know if its possible to use tailwind for the css that should be set to dompdf?

Comment: I believe so as long as you include the compiled version. I'm not 100% sure though that all css properties are supported by domPdf, you should check out the docs to make sure.